# Using @HTML.editor to generate SelectListItem checkboxes?

Tags: c#, asp.net-mvc, asp.net-mvc-4

I'm super new to ASP.NET MVC. I'm so new I'm still bad at wording my questions...I hope I can make some sense with this...

Basically, what I want is in the form a list of checkboxes with a list of furniture items from a database table. The table currently has 20 items; the columns are ID and Name.

I have multiple forms, so I have been using this in the view:

```
<form method="post">
@foreach (var property in ViewData.ModelMetadata.Properties)
{
    <div class="form-group">
        <label asp-for="@property.PropertyName">
            @(property.DisplayName ?? property.PropertyName)
        </label>
        @Html.Editor(property.PropertyName)
        @Html.ValidationMessage(property.PropertyName, new { @class = "help-block" })
    </div>


}
<input type="submit" value="@ViewBag.Button" />
</form>
```

For this particular form, I am using this code in the ViewModel (there are other properties too):

```
    public List<SelectListItem> Furniture { get; set; }        

    public DeliveryViewModel(IEnumerable<Furniture> furniture)
    {
        Furniture = new List<SelectListItem>();

        foreach (Furniture piece in furniture)
        {
            Furniture.Add(new SelectListItem
            {
                Value = piece.ID.ToString(),
                Text = piece.Name
            });
        }
    }

    public DeliveryViewModel() {}

}
}
```

And the controller (yes, it's called Furnitures. I should fix that.):

```
public IActionResult Delivery()
    {
        List<Furniture> furniture = context.Furnitures.ToList();
        return View("Index", new DeliveryViewModel(furniture));
    }
```

Basically, when I fire up the application, instead of getting anything resembling a furniture list, I'm getting something that looks like "FalseFalseFalseFalseFalseFalse" for each item in the table. I was just trying to get a dropdown at first, but I can't even get that.

I want to keep using the View code if I can, because I have multiple forms that use that code and work fine.  Is that possible? It seems like a lot of solutions for a list of checkboxes involve @HTML.checkboxfor or some variation thereof and that would compromise my being able to reuse this View. I also have a lot more properties in the ViewModel and suspect I'll need to make lots of changes as I work on this project so making a special form for this would be annoying.

Do I make sense? Can I be helped?

Comment: You need to abandon this - what you are attempting can never work and never bind correctly

Comment: I had a feeling this would be the case. Ah well. It was worth a shot.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

If addressing the "how do I build a list of items with checkboxes" is the core concern of your question, that's somewhat simple to get started.

I would define a view model for each "checkbox item":

```cs
public class CheckBoxItem
{
    public int ID { get; set; }
    public string Name { get; set; }
    public bool IsChecked { get; set; }
}
```

The SelectListItem is pretty much the same, except the Value property is a string - the CheckBoxItem class I'm proposing lets you use it directly for database lookups (assuming your row IDs are integers).

In the ASP.NET MVC framework, if you have a view with the same name as a class, you can use the [HtmlHelper.EditorFor](https://msdn.microsoft.com/en-us/library/ee402949(v=vs.118).aspx) method to automatically have that view selected and rendered, like so:

#### CheckBoxItem.cshtml

```
@model Fully.Qualified.Namespace.CheckBoxItem

<div class="checkbox-list-item>
    <div class="form-check">
        <label class="form-check-label">
            @Html.CheckBoxFor(m => m.IsChecked, new { @class="form-check-input" })
            @Model.Name
        </label
    </div>
    @Html.HiddenFor(m => m.ID)
    @Html.HiddenFor(m => m.Name)
</div>
```

Then, assuming this was your parent view:

#### Furniture.cshtml

```
@model Fully.Qualified.Namespace.FurnitureListModel

<div class="checkbox-list">
    @Html.EditorFor(m => m.Items)
</div>
```

with this as the model:

```cs
public class FurnitureListModel
{
    public ICollection<CheckBoxItem> Items { get; set; }
}
```

The `EditorFor` helper will automatically iterate through the collection property, `Items`, rendering the view for each item.

When the form is submitted, you would check the `IsChecked` property of each item (or use LINQ to select all of the items where it's true) to see which items were checked - the checkbox helper will build inputs for true and false, where the true value is only submitted if the checkbox is checked.